# Simple Question: Characteristic Function of Pre-Image

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose $f$ is a measurable function.  Let B be any measurable set.  I was reading a text on ergodic theory and it states that: 
$\chi_{f^{-1}(B)} =\chi_B \circ f$.
I don't understand why this is true.  Why is the composition of $\chi_B$ and $f$ equal to the left-hand side? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(\chi_B\circ f)(a)=\chi_B(f(a))
=\cases{1&if $f(a)\in B$\\
0&otherwise}
=\cases{1&if $a\in f^{-1}(B)$\\
0&otherwise}=\chi_{f^{-1}(B)}(a).$$

Comment: I see makes perfect sense

Comment: I should have went straight back to the definition, thanks